# Add duplicated values of a php array to another and keep the same keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP Array, and I want to extract from it the duplicated values and keep the corresponding keys for each value, in a new Array.

This is my starting Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC123-A
    [1] => BG231-B
    [2] => ABC123-A
    [3] => BG231-E
    [4] => BG231-F
    [5] => BG231-G
    [6] => BG231-H
    [7] => ABC123-A
    [8] => BG231-J
    [9] => BG231-K
    [10] => ABC123-A
)
```

And this is what I want to have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC123-A
    [2] => ABC123-A
    [7] => ABC123-A
    [10] => ABC123-A
)
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What if there are more than one duplicated value?

Comment: I have more than one duplicated value, I want to keep them (with the corresponding key), because I need these values...

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10432377/367456) get's you all duplicated values - every duplicate value has it's own array and is keyed by the value. Each array contains the original keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this out:

```
$return = array_unique($array);
var_dump(
    array_diff($array, array_diff($return, array_diff_assoc($array, $return)))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has no function build in that does this, but you can combine [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array_count_values) and [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect) to obtain the array(s) you want.

The first one is used to know which values do exist in your array (and counts them so it's easy to filter out every non-duplicate one), and the second function does preserve the keys. If you know the duplicated value upfront, you only need to use the latter:

```
$duplicatesArray = array_intersect($array, array($duplicate));
```

Full example:

```
/**
 * @param array $array
 * @param int $threshold (optional) minimum number of elements per group
 * @return array
 */
function array_group_by_value(array $array, $threshold = 1)
{
    $grouped = array();
    foreach(array_count_values($array) as $value => $count)
    {
        if ($count < $threshold) continue;
        $grouped[$value] = array_intersect($array, array($value));
    }
    return $grouped;
}
```

Usage Example:

```
$test = array('a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c');

var_dump(array_group_by_value($test, 2));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "a"
  }
  ["b"]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need all duplicates in one array, You can try:

```
$unique = array_unique($array); //get unique values
$diff = array_diff_assoc($array, $unique); //get duplicates
$intersect = array_intersect($unique, $diff); //get unique values with duplicates
return $intersect+$diff; //join unique with duplicates and duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$duplicated=null;

foreach($yourarray as $k => $v){
    foreach($yourarray as $k2 => $v2){
        if($v == $v2 && $k2 != $k){
            $duplicated[$k]=$v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I recommend this answer (versus other answers) because it is always making _n_ x _n_ conditional checks with the nested loop.  I mean, the same outcome is achieved with fewer iterations by implementing a `break`. https://3v4l.org/Doo0R  I'll admit that I haven't thought too deeply about this task, but `array_count_values()` feels like a direct way of identifying duplicates without re-searching the input array over and over.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `array_unique()`.http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Judging by the question, this is the opposite. OP is asking to KEEP the duplicates, not remove them